# SQL BreakDown Values Queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have these values :

```
Numbers 
4651230913
4651278185
4651501024
4651530913
4651543447
QCIM1E123942
4651546422
QCIM1E123946
4651558787
QCIM1E123948
4651574839
```

Now I just want to create two columns and my output will be:

```
Numbers       QC Value
4651230913    null
4651278185    null
4651501024    null
4651530913    null
4651543447    QCIM1E123942
4651546422    QCIM1E123946
4651558787    QCIM1E123948
4651574839    null
```

Comment: could you please explain with some more detail? also improve formatting because the data is unreadable and it is not clear your goal.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. You would need to have mechanism to order your data and with what you posted you don't have that. You can't rely on the "order" of the data in the table because by definition a table is an unordered set.

Comment: in my question,we have one column with multiple rows,and there are two types of value,one is purely numeric and another is started by 'QC' ,like in my given example,when we have 2nd row with numeric than we will put null value in parallel column,if this is started  by 'QC' than we will put QC value,if we have more than 3 QC value than we will make comma separated value...so please tell me how can I find out ...

Comment: "2nd row"?   What determines which row is the "2nd row"?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE(n VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Numbers VALUES
('QCI111111'),
('4651230913'),
('4651278185'),
('4651501024'),
('4651530913'),
('4651543447'),
('QCIM1E123942'),
('QCIM1E123943'),
('4651546422'),
('QCIM1E123946'),
('4651558787'),
('QCIM1E123948'),
('4651574839')

;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn 
             FROM @Numbers)
SELECT CASE WHEN c.n LIKE 'QCI%' THEN NULL ELSE c.n END AS [Numbers], oa.n AS [QC Value] 
FROM cte c
OUTER APPLY(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ci.n FROM cte ci 
            WHERE ci.rn >= c.rn AND 
                  ci.n LIKE 'QCI%' AND 
                  ci.rn < (SELECT MIN(rn) FROM cte cm 
                           WHERE cm.rn > c.rn + 1 AND cm.n NOT LIKE 'QCI%') AND
                  ((SELECT n FROM cte WHERE rn = c.rn + 1) LIKE 'QCI%' OR (c.n LIKE 'QCI%' AND c.rn = 1))
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS n) oa
WHERE c.n NOT LIKE 'QCI%' OR (c.n LIKE 'QCI%' AND c.rn = 1)
```

Output:

```
Numbers     QC Value
NULL        QCI111111
4651230913  NULL
4651278185  NULL
4651501024  NULL
4651530913  NULL
4651543447  QCIM1E123942, QCIM1E123943
4651546422  QCIM1E123946
4651558787  QCIM1E123948
4651574839  NULL
```

Change `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` to appropriate column of your table that guarantees ordering.

Comment: yes Giorgi, I want like this,but if we have QC values multiple times before next numeric value,than we will show multiple QC value with comma separated, like                                                                                                            .Numbers     QC Value
4651230913  NULL
4651278185  NULL
4651501024  NULL
4651530913  NULL
4651543447  QCIM1E123942,QC1,QC2,QC4
4651546422  QCIM1E123946,QC3
4651558787  QCIM1E123948
4651574839  NULL

Comment: it's very nice my friend, but see that if my first value is started by QC than It doesn't show that value,i mean if I have this condition :         Numbers                                                                                    QCIM1E123942
4651546422
QCIM1E123946                                                                             QCIM1E123948
4651574839

Comment: What number do you want to see if first value is qc?

Comment: if I get QC value first than this doesn't work ,for that QC value we will have null value for Numbers,please do it